# Foursquare for Beginners

Tags: foursquare

I am looking for a "dumbed down" tutorial that teaches how to code with the API. I have experience with HTML and PHP but i honestly don't get most of the Foursquare Tutorials. I feel like there is some simple stuff I am supposed to know but I just dont. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. The question as it is very broad an not  easily answerable. Questions that have a concrete problem often get you better answers. Could you edit your question to address specific issues you are having?